# How do I find the theorical number of maximum steps to find the root for fixedpoint iteration?

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-iteration

How do I find the theorical number of maximum steps to find the root for fixedpoint iteration? for example for this equation

```
  x^2-5x+5 = 0 on [1,2] tolerance 10^-2 p0 = 1
```

Comment: the number of steps generally is infinite...

Comment: What fixed-point iteration? You only provided a polynomial with a sign change in that interval.

Comment: have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method